# Why am I getting an error in AWS-S3 static website json?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying to host a static Website using AWS-S3 with the Json Editing for Rules here are the rules.

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::www.elementsoftech.tech/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This was on AWS documentation to what to do I did exactly what they said and I am getting an error saying:

> Expected params.WebsiteConfiguration.RoutingRules to be an Array

Answer (score 0):

There has been a small change in user interface of AWS S3 bucket overview. I'm thinking you're most probably adding the bucket policy in "Redirection rules" section.

[image]

In order to update bucket policy, go to "Permissions" tab of your S3 object and paste the bucket policy.